# Azure CD Issue : Failed to fetch App Service 'myAppServiceName' publishing credentials

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy my release on a azure web App. It's not working and I don't know what to do. Maybe I'm missing something in the configuration in my app service or in my release pipeline. I've got the following error

```
Failed to fetch App Service 'myAppServiceName' publishing credentials. Error: Could not fetch access token for Managed Service Principal.
```

And here is a block of my debug :

```
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4761242Z ##[debug]Predeployment Step Started
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4776374Z ##[debug]33ddf4aa-03c4-4031-95fa-e2083d49cc9e data subscriptionid = xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4776793Z ##[debug]33ddf4aa-03c4-4031-95fa-e2083d49cc9e data subscriptionname = Paiement à l’utilisation
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4777798Z ##[debug]33ddf4aa-03c4-4031-95fa-e2083d49cc9e auth param serviceprincipalid = null
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4778094Z ##[debug]33ddf4aa-03c4-4031-95fa-e2083d49cc9e data environmentAuthorityUrl = https://login.windows.net/
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4781237Z ##[debug]33ddf4aa-03c4-4031-95fa-e2083d49cc9e auth param tenantid = ***
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4782509Z ##[debug]33ddf4aa-03c4-4031-95fa-e2083d49cc9e=https://management.azure.com/
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4782769Z ##[debug]33ddf4aa-03c4-4031-95fa-e2083d49cc9e data environment = AzureCloud
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4785012Z ##[debug]33ddf4aa-03c4-4031-95fa-e2083d49cc9e auth scheme = ManagedServiceIdentity
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4785626Z ##[debug]33ddf4aa-03c4-4031-95fa-e2083d49cc9e data msiclientId = undefined
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4785882Z ##[debug]33ddf4aa-03c4-4031-95fa-e2083d49cc9e data activeDirectoryServiceEndpointResourceId = https://management.core.windows.net/
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4786107Z ##[debug]33ddf4aa-03c4-4031-95fa-e2083d49cc9e data AzureKeyVaultServiceEndpointResourceId = https://vault.azure.net
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4786348Z ##[debug]33ddf4aa-03c4-4031-95fa-e2083d49cc9e data AzureKeyVaultDnsSuffix = vault.azure.net
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4786525Z ##[debug]33ddf4aa-03c4-4031-95fa-e2083d49cc9e auth param authenticationType = null
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4786735Z ##[debug]33ddf4aa-03c4-4031-95fa-e2083d49cc9e data EnableAdfsAuthentication = false
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4792324Z ##[debug]{"subscriptionID":"mysubscriptionID","subscriptionName":"Paiement à l’utilisation","servicePrincipalClientID":null,"environmentAuthorityUrl":"https://login.windows.net/","tenantID":"***","url":"https://management.azure.com/","environment":"AzureCloud","scheme":"ManagedServiceIdentity","activeDirectoryResourceID":"https://management.azure.com/","azureKeyVaultServiceEndpointResourceId":"https://vault.azure.net","azureKeyVaultDnsSuffix":"vault.azure.net","authenticationType":null,"isADFSEnabled":false,"applicationTokenCredentials":{"clientId":null,"domain":"***","baseUrl":"https://management.azure.com/","authorityUrl":"https://login.windows.net/","activeDirectoryResourceId":"https://management.azure.com/","isAzureStackEnvironment":false,"scheme":0,"isADFSEnabled":false}}
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4809400Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'myAppServiceName'
2019-04-11T08:25:35.4846967Z ##[debug][GET]http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://management.azure.com/
2019-04-11T08:25:35.5443632Z ##[debug]Deployment Failed with Error: Error: Failed to fetch App Service 'myAppServiceName' publishing credentials. Error: Could not fetch access token for Managed Service Principal. Please configure Managed Service Identity (MSI) for virtual machine 'https://aka.ms/azure-msi-docs'. Status code: 400, status message: Bad Request
2019-04-11T08:25:35.5444488Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2019-04-11T08:25:35.5501745Z ##[error]Error: Failed to fetch App Service 'myAppServiceName' publishing credentials. Error: Could not fetch access token for Managed Service Principal. Please configure Managed Service Identity (MSI) for virtual machine 'https://aka.ms/azure-msi-docs'. Status code: 400, status message: Bad Request
2019-04-11T08:25:35.5511780Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Failed to fetch App Service 'myAppServiceName' publishing credentials. Error: Could not fetch access token for Managed Service Principal. Please configure Managed Service Identity (MSI) for virtual machine 'https://aka.ms/azure-msi-docs'. Status code: 400, status message: Bad Request
2019-04-11T08:25:35.5512729Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: Failed to fetch App Service 'myAppServiceName' publishing credentials. Error: Could not fetch access token for Managed Service Principal. Please configure Managed Service Identity (MSI) for virtual machine 'https://aka.ms/azure-msi-docs'. Status code: 400, status message: Bad Request
2019-04-11T08:25:35.5512828Z Failed to add release annotation. Error: Failed to get App service 'myAppServiceName' application settings. Error: Could not fetch access token for Managed Service Principal. Please configure Managed Service Identity (MSI) for virtual machine 'https://aka.ms/azure-msi-docs'. Status code: 400, status message: Bad Request
2019-04-11T08:25:35.5645194Z (node:5004) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Failed to fetch App Service 'myAppServiceName' publishing profile. Error: Could not fetch access token for Managed Service Principal. Please configure Managed Service Identity (MSI) for virtual machine 'https://aka.ms/azure-msi-docs'. Status code: 400, status message: Bad Request
2019-04-11T08:25:35.5759915Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure App Service
```

And some screenshot of

[azure missing configuration ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQuDb.jpg)

[release pipeline config 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBngN.jpg)

[release pipeline config 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SLti.jpg)

[release pipeline config 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6sBi.jpg)

Let me know if you need more informations.. I'm new in this so maybe missing simple things... Best regards

Answer (score 3):

A simple typo can also be the reason for this error message.

You will get this error message even though if it's just a typo or wrong value in your "slotName".

Please do ensure that the "slotName" you've given is the actual slotname (the default is 'production'). So if you've added a slot that's called 'stage' then inside the portal it will have your '/stage' or '-stage', but it's still just called 'stage'.

[image]

I know several have had this error message shown and none of the above helped them out (I faced the same issue the first time).

Answer (score 2):

do you have setting identity Status On ? 
like below 
[image]

Comment: We do and we are also seeing this problem AND it it is not "fixed" by rerunning release

Answer (score 1):

In my case, we had just moved our app service to a new resource group, but the pipeline was still referencing the old resource group. Correcting the resource group fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

My research indicated this to be an intermittent problem.
I redeployed 2 times and it worked.
The first redeploy - just seemed to wait for ages to connect to an available agent, so I cancelled that too, and redeployed - which worked without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue or if someone had this issue, all I did was just to rerun the release and it well went well. Hopefully someone has saved time by just re-releasing, if this wont work then probably try something else.

Comment: This does not always work in re-running way.

Answer (score 0):

If deploying to a slot, this error can be a red herring.  Check the error to see what scope it is looking at and make sure it is not /resourcegroup/undefined.

If so, make sure you have specified the resourceGroupName parameter of the AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 task.  It is required when deployToSlotOrASE is true.